# foreign_key: method doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have two models

```
class LunchSet < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sides
end

class Side < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :set_id

  belongs_to :lunch_set, foreign_key: :set_id

end
```

but still, when i create object new LunchSet 'l', with id = 1, and new Side 's' with set_id = 1, typing l.sides just give me sql error that says

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: sides.lunch_set_id: SELECT "sides".* FROM "sides"  WHERE "sides"."lunch_set_id" = 52
```

as you can see it is still looking for a column 'lunch_set_id' instead of 'set_id' like i want...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the foreign key in the LunchSet model

```
class LunchSet < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sides, :class_name => 'Side', :foreign_key => 'set_id'
end

class Side < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :set_id

  belongs_to :lunch_set, :class_name => 'LunchSet', :foreign_key => 'set_id'

end
```

Comment: is it showing the same error? If you are checking it using rails console, please restart it.

Comment: reload! command some times does not work. can you please stop that console and start it again to check it?

Comment: you were kinda right, it checks for the correct column now, but gives me empty array when results should be

Comment: try adding records for the two tables in console. l = LunchSet.create() AND Side.create([{:set_id => l.id}, {:set_id => l.id}]) .Then try l.sides.

Comment: well, do you have any idea why it only works when im using this syntax you gave me and not if i do it like s = Side.create; s.set_id = 53? when i do it and then call l.sides it doesnt give me this latest Side...

Comment: s = Side.create; s.set_id = 53 AND then you have to save it using s.save Else it is not going to save into db.